# Python, creating a list of lists while creating incremented list names

Tags: python, list

The program starts with taking in a string. The program reads in the string then divides it into different variables using indexing. So:

```
var_1 = string[position] + string[position+1]
var_2 = string[position+2] + string[position+3]
```

so on and so on. I use a loop and increment the position.

I want to have the first 8 variables saved to a list. The next 8 variables are saved to the next list, and so on and so on.

The problem is the input string length can be many different lengths. They string is data that is always the correct length to make a whole number of lists. But it could be two lists to dozens of lists.

I need to access the previous list of data to do calculations.

I would like to do something like:

```
difference = list_2[3] - list_1[3]
list_2 += [difference] # which I think makes the difference the new 9th item in list_2
```

The problem is I don't know how many lists there might be. I was trying to name the lists incrementally. Then when I pull the information I would be able to index the values by using list_name[position#]. I don't know how to increment the list name so I can do the indexing.

How do I make incremented list names for indexing?
The first reason is, I don't want to make a huge number of names of lists (especially when I won't use them all)
The second reason is, I don't know how many lists I will need to make until the string of data is input?

I will know how many lists to make by taking the len(string) / 32 # there are 32 characters to fill all the values in the variables in each list.
So if I have 128 characters I want:

```
list_1
list_2
list_3
list_4
```

but if I have 416 characters in the string I want the list names to go up to:

```
...
list_12
list_13
```

Thanks, SDD

Comment: You are looking for a list of lists `[[entries of list1], [entries of list2], ...]`

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this ? Please post code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var1
var2
var3
...
```

make `var` a list, so you have:

```
var[0]
var[1]
var[2]
...
```

The entries in a list can be lists themselves.  As a general rule, if you ever have a programming problem that seems to require the creation of a bunch of variables that all hold the same kind of thing, you probably want to create a single container (like a list or a dict) that holds all those values so that you can easily iterate over them (no matter how many there are) instead of having to type out a bunch of individual names and being limited to a certain fixed number of them.

Here's a very quick example in the REPL of how you could build a list of eight-element lists of two-character strings based on a single input string:

```
>>> string = "asldkfjalskdfjalskdjflaskdjflaskdjflaksdjfkjsldkfjsldakjfsdlkaaa"
>>> var = [[]]
>>> for i in range(0, len(string), 2):
...     if len(var[-1]) == 8:
...         var.append([])
...     var[-1].append(string[i:i+2])
...
>>> var
[['as', 'ld', 'kf', 'ja', 'ls', 'kd', 'fj', 'al'], ['sk', 'dj', 'fl', 'as', 'kd', 'jf', 'la', 'sk'], ['dj', 'fl', 'ak', 'sd', 'jf', 'kj', 'sl', 'dk'], ['fj', 'sl', 'da', 'kj', 'fs', 'dl', 'ka', 'aa']]
>>> var[0]
['as', 'ld', 'kf', 'ja', 'ls', 'kd', 'fj', 'al']
>>> var[1]
['sk', 'dj', 'fl', 'as', 'kd', 'jf', 'la', 'sk']
>>> var[2]
['dj', 'fl', 'ak', 'sd', 'jf', 'kj', 'sl', 'dk']
>>> var[3]
['fj', 'sl', 'da', 'kj', 'fs', 'dl', 'ka', 'aa']
```

Here we're taking advantage of the `range` function to help us iterate over the indices of the string in steps of 2, and we're using string slicing (`string[i:i+2]`) to easily grab those two-character slices.

`var[-1]` is always the last element of the list `var`, which starts as a list containing a single empty list (`[[]]`); as we iterate through the string, we're always appending those two characters onto the end of the last list.

We also always check to see if `var[-1]` has reached eight elements yet; if so, that sublist is done, so we `append` a new empty list to the end of `var` so we can start a new one.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. This should work well for what I am trying to do. All the values are made up of 2 character strings, so I will be able to use the range function, which is cleaner than my much larger loop. Some values are multiple 2 character strings concatenated together. I didn't think of opening a list of lists, starting with an empty list. Also I didn't know that you could negative index a list, as in your example var[-1]. I made a work around with list length. These are great tips, and thanks for explaining them in detail!